# Self-intersection of canonical divisor of an elliptic surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, surfaces

Let S
be an elliptic surface over a curve C
and K
a canonical divisor on S.
Why is it that K^2 = 0? It should come from the fact that K is the pullback from the canonical divisor of C.

I think that since the fibers have genus 1, the pullback lies inside a fiber, so Kx*Kx = 2g-2 = 0

Does it make any sense?

Comment: Your idea that $K$ is the pullback of the canonical divisor of $C$ is not quite right. There is a precise formula for the canonical divisor on a (minimal) elliptic surface, simply called "the canonical bundle formula", which shows the $K$ differs from the pullback of the canonical divisor on $C$ a bit. You can find discussions on the formula in, e.g., ArXiv: 0907.0298. On the other hand, $K$ is vertical, i.e., lies in a fiber. This can be seen by using the adjunction formula: if $F$ is a general, elliptic fiber, then $F.(F+K)=F.K=2g(F)-2=0$.